# wamp 3 (w/ tool) virtual host stopped working

Tags: apache, wamp

My WAMP 3 vhost (vhost was setup with WAMP tool) stopped working, here are my particulars:

### hosts file

```
127.0.0.1           localhost
::1                 localhost
127.0.0.1           projectx
::1                 projectx
```

### http.conf

```
...

Listen 127.0.0.1:80
Listen [::1]:80

...

LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so

...
```

### httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot C:/company/profordable/server/local/wamp/server/wamp64/www
    <Directory  "C:/company/profordable/server/local/wamp/server/wamp64/www/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName projectx
    DocumentRoot c:/company/profordable/projects/projectx/www
    <Directory  "c:/company/profordable/projects/projectx/www/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is the apache access log:

```
::1 - - [17/Aug/2016:17:53:34 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 3054
```

which I think means there is a redirect going on, because when I click the link to go to http://projectx/ it rests on the localhost main page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Nate

Comment: So what did you change just before it stopped working

Comment: Why did you feel the need to change the default `Listen 0.0.0.0:80` to `Listen 127.0.0.1:80`

Comment: last thing I did before it changed was (i think) switch out my dummy index.php file with my actual project index.php file and then I hit Ctrl+Shift+R

Comment: I thought 0.0.0.0:80 was incorrect, is that equivalent to 127.0.0.1:80 ??

Comment: No its equivalent to any ip your PC may be given